# Using contains in linq

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I have a filtered list which returns all the distinctIds from MenuTable

```
  var _parentList = _employee.Designation.Role.MenuRoles
                                                .Select(x => new
                                                {
                                                    MenuParentID = x.Menu.ParentID
                                                })
                                                .DistinctBy(x => x.MenuParentID)
                                                .OrderBy(x => x.MenuParentID)
                                                .ToList();
```

I want to select all the items from `menutable` which is in `_parentList`

This is what i have tried and an error is coming on `_parentList.Contains(x.Id)` which says `Best overloaded match for System.Generic.contains has some invalid arguments.`

```
 MenuParentList = _db.Menus.Where(x => _parentList.Contains(x.Id))
                           .Select(x => new SMS.Models.ViewModel.DashboardVM.MenuParent
                           {
                               MenuParentID = x.Id,
                               MenuParentName = x.MenuName
                           })
                           .ToList()
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: What is your issue here?

Comment: I can't see any problem in your code. It should work.

Comment: `_parentList` doesn't contains only `Ids`, it is a list of different `type` and you are trying to figure out `Ids` in it

Comment: the type of `x.Id` is not same as type of elements in `_parentList`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj ,@Kazem   I think the difference is `_parentlist` contains `nullable int` and `x.id` is `not nullable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cf. this code:

```
.Select(x => new
{
    MenuParentID = x.Menu.ParentID
})
```

This results in a list of anonymous objects with one property called MenuParentID, instead of a list of integers. The compiler creates a type for you that structurally looks like this (note that the compiler generates a non-usable class name behind the scenes instead of `AnonymousType1`, but you get the idea):

```
class AnonymousType1
{
    public int MenuParentID {get;set;}
}
```

And `_parentList` would be of type `List<AnonymousType1>`.

Adjust your code as follows:

```
var _parentList = _employee.Designation.Role.MenuRoles
                       .Select(x => x.Menu.ParentID)
                       .Distinct()
                       .OrderBy(id => id)
                       .ToList();
```

Now `_parentList` is of type `List<int>`.

You can read more about the concept of anonymous types on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx